# sys.refcount() returning much greater value then expected python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning about GIL in python and tried to run sys.refcount() and recevied value of 148. This might be a very simple question , any help would be appreciated.

Why is the value 148 and not 2 ?

```
import sys

c = 1
print(sys.getrefcount(c))

>>> 148
```

Comment: Why do you think the value should be `2`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because there’s one strong reference made by “c”, and another made by passing the object as a parameter to “getrefcount”

Answer (score 4):

`int` is special.

Its values are very numerous (pun intended) and small, which is the worst-case as far object overhead (it wastes time to allocate, GCs become slower because they have more heap objects to scan, and wastes time to reference count and deallocate). Typically language runtimes go to pretty great lengths to try to optimizations special cases like `int`, `bool`, etc.

Depending on the particular implementation of Python, it's possible that `int` objects are represented as:

1. Regular, run-of-the-mill heap-allocated objects (i.e., no special optimizations).
2. As regular heap-allocated objects, but with a pool of shared objects used to represent all the most common values. (e.g. every instance of `1` is the same object, referenced
   everywhere where a `1` is used)
3. Or as a [tagged
   pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer), which involves no heap-allocation at all (for suitably small integer values).

In case 2 or 3, its reference count will not be what you might expect, had it been a "normal" object.

Comment: I shudder to imagine a tagged-pointer implementation for Python. Not only would you have to special-case all the arithmetic, but proxy all the attribute accesses too.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the special-casing was worth it, at least in Objective C and Ruby. You might be interested in https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html

Comment: "GCs become smaller"? I guess you meant "slower"? And at least in CPython, I think ints aren't registered for the `gc` garbage collector, as they can't be part of a reference *cycle*.

Comment: Haha yeah, I meant slower. "I think ints aren't registered for the gc garbage collector, as they can't be part of a reference cycle." Oo, that's clever. By the way, you have enough reputation to suggest an edit. It would automatically notify me and I can just approve the correction

Comment: Hmm, then again, ints can of course be list elements, and those lists *can* be part of cycles, so when the `gc` garbage collector deletes a list, its int elements get their references decreased and might get deleted as well. So in that sense ints might make even the `gc` garbage collection slower as well, just the word "scan" sounds like something else to me (the process `gc` does to find cycles). About editing: I actually have too much reputation already, don't need approval anymore, hence I hesitate.

Comment: "I actually have too much reputation already, don't need approval anymore, hence I hesitate." I have that worry too! I wish there was a checkbox that would let me request the author's approval for cases when I'd want their blessing before making an edit

Answer (score 4):

Your Python code isn't the only thing running. Much of the Python standard library is written *in* Python, and depending on which shell you use that can cause quite a few modules to be imported before the first thing you type. Here under CPython 3.10.0's IDLE:

```
>>> import sys
>>> len(sys.modules)
159
```

So just getting to the prompt imported 159(!) modules "under the covers".

"Small" integer objects are shared, across uses, by the CPython implementation. So every instance of 3 across all those modules adds to 3's refcount. Here are some others:

```py
>>> for i in range(-10, 11):
...     print(i, sys.getrefcount(i))
-10 3
-9 3
-8 3
-7 3
-6 3
-5 9
-4 5
-3 12
-2 25
-1 190
0 914
1 804
2 363
3 144
4 202
5 83
6 83
7 38
8 128
9 54
10 64
```

So 3 is "pretty popular", but 0 is the easy winner. Nothing else is using, e.g., -10 or -9, though.

But do note that *knowing* this is of no actual value to you. Whether and when Python shares immutable objects is implementation-defined, and can (and does!) change across releases.

Comment: On my 3.8 install at the command line, `len(sys.modules)` is only 36. Just what is IDLE doing?

Comment: IDLE is a sizable application all of its own, including 23 of its own modules, and needing to import support for threads, multiple processes, interprocess communication (particularly sockets), Tk, ..., and all the modules those in _turn_ import.